# Using asynchronous Node.js functions with Python subprocesses

Tags: python, node.js, asynchronous, subprocess, node.js-fs

I have an `app.js` file that uses `fs.watchFile()` to check for changes in a text file. The changes are then outputed to the console. I have a `python.py` that I would like to use this JS file while the same time running code for the GPIO pins on a RasberryPi (the GPIO code is not shown here for simplicity). When running `python.py` the program gets stuck after priting "after start" which means that the JS file is at fault. I have tried using Python `asyncio` as well but I've received the same result as when I don't use it. Is there a way of allowing an asynchronous process on Node.js to run, while letting be a Python subprocess and allow the rest of the code to continue normally? Should I try running Python using Node.js instead?

**app.js:**

```
const fs = require('fs');

function main() {
    const text_file= '/home/user/git/corp/file.txt';
    const text = fs.readFileSync(policies_file, "utf8");
    console.log(text);    
    fs.watchFile(text_file, {bigint: false, persistent: true, interval: 1}, (curr, prev) => { 
            const text= fs.readFileSync(text_file, "utf8");
            console.log(text);
    }
main();
```

**python.py**

```
import subprocess
import asyncio

async def subproc():
    print("start subprocess")
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/node","/home/user/git/corp/prudens-js/node/app.js", ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print("after start")
    out = proc.communicate()
    print("after finish")
    print(out)  

async def main():
    print("start")
    await asyncio.gather(subproc())
    print("waiting")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

"the program gets stuck after priting "after start" which means that the JS file is at fault."

Not at all.  The problem is that `proc.communicate()` is blocking, even inside an `async` function, so it will block `python.py` until `app.js` completes - which it never does.

If you want to read output from the process as it is produced use `proc.stdout.readline()` instead.

Don't use async for this, use threads - one for the subprocess communication and another for the GPIO.

e.g.

```py
import subprocess
import threading

def subproc():
    print("start subprocess")
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/node", "app.js", ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print("after start")
    while 1:
        out = proc.stdout.readline()
        print("out:", out)
        
def main():
    t = threading.Thread(target=subproc)
    t.start()
    print("thread started")
    # do other stuff here in the main thread
    
    # but I'll just wait on the thread - which will never complete
    t.join()
    print("thread complete")

main()
```

Comment: `app.js` should output something since I'm using `fs.watch()` and changing the files and but is happening. It's definitely being blocked as you said. Any tips as to how to use threads? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: It was even worse than I thought, as your app.js never completes, so `communicate` would block indefinitely. Anyway, updated the answer with `readline` and threads - not sure if that is what you are after, but it works for me.

Comment: When I try to implement it I will mark it as solved or ask you to clarify further! Thank you!